# multiplication with dataframes in r

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. One is called data, like

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2 ),
           Number = c(1,2, 1, 2),
           Answer = c(1, 2, 3, 2 )
           )
```

The other is called weights, like

```
weights <- data.frame ( Number=c(1,2), 
            weight1=c(0.5,1), 
            weight2=c(1, 1)
          )
```

What I want is to use Data$Answers to multiply Weights$weight based on Number (in both dataframes). The final results should be look like

```
  ID Number Answer Answer*Weights1  Answer*Weights2
1  1      1      1   1*0.5             1*1
2  1      2      2   2*1               2*1
3  2      1      3   3*0.5             3*1
4  2      2      2   2*1               2*1
```

How can I achieve it? Your inputs will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data <- merge(data, weights, by = "Number")
data <- transform(data,
                  A1 = Answer * weight1,
                  A2 = Answer * weight2)
#  Number ID Answer weight1 weight2  A1 A2
#1      1  1      1     0.5       1 0.5  1
#2      1  2      3     0.5       1 1.5  3
#3      2  1      2     1.0       1 2.0  2
#4      2  2      2     1.0       1 2.0  2
```

Comment: Read some tutorial to learn how to sort a data.frame. This does work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
 library(dplyr)
 left_join(data, weights, by="Number") %>% 
 select(ID:Answer, Answer_weight1=weight1, Answer_weight2=weight2) %>%
 mutate_each(funs(Answer*.), contains("weight"))
#    ID Number Answer Answer_weight1 Answer_weight2
# 1  1      1      1            0.5              1
# 2  1      2      2            2.0              2
# 3  2      1      3            1.5              3
# 4  2      2      2            2.0              2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do this using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
setDT(data)         ## convert data.frame to data.table by reference
setDT(weights)

setkey(data, Number)    ## set the key columns to join by
data[weights, c("Answer1", "Answer2") := 
           list(Answer * weight1, Answer * weight2)]
```

We perform a join, but directly create the required columns without the intermediate variables (`weight1`, `weight2`), and is therefore quite memory efficient. It modifies `data` *in place*.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want those entries in the `Answers*Weights1` and `Answers*Weights2` columns to be strings and not actually multiplication, like you have in your original post:

```
data <- cbind(data,
              paste(data[, 3], weights[, 2], sep = "*"),
              paste(data[, 3], weights[, 3], sep = "*"))
names(data)[4:5] <- c("Answer*Weights1", "Answer*Weights2")
#   ID Number Answer Answer*Weights1 Answer*Weights2
# 1  1      1      1           1*0.5             1*1
# 2  1      2      2             2*1             2*1
# 3  2      1      3           3*0.5             3*1
# 4  2      2      2             2*1             2*1
```

Or if you want numbers instead of strings

```
data[, 4] <- data[, 3] * weights[, 2]
data[, 5] <- data[, 3] * weights[, 3]
names(data)[4:5] <- c("Answer*Weights1", "Answer*Weights2")
#   ID Number Answer Answer*Weights1 Answer*Weights2
# 1  1      1      1             0.5               1
# 2  1      2      2             2.0               2
# 3  2      1      3             1.5               3
# 4  2      2      2             2.0               2
```